# Change content, class and then send Ajax request on Button click issue

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, hyperlink

I have a hyperlink styled as a button that will result in them friending or unfriending a specific person on the website. However, I need to change the class, and content of the hyperlink when it is clicked, as well as send an Ajax request to run a PHP script to add the friend or delete them with the 2 id's (one is `$user->data()->id` and the other is `$timeline->data()->id`) which is done using PHP.

a) I am trying to change the content of the hyperlink with the following code:

```
function al(){
var friend = document.getElementById('friend');
friend.innerHTML = 'hi';
}

<a href="#" id="friend" class="unfriend" onclick="al();">Unfriend</a>
```

b) any suggestions on how to do the rest? can I change the class by using Javascripts `.className` function?

jsfiddle: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VaMoose/rC2sS/2/)

I have also tried using:

```
$('#friend').onclick(function(){
var friend = document.getElementById('friend');
fiend.innerHTML = 'hi';
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can do with Jquery easily.

Comment: how then? I am new to Javascript

Comment: `friend.className = 'new_class'` replaces the current classes with that class only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send data to the server you can use Jquery.ajax to Post the data.  See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

To test if the element is of a certain class

try

```
if ($("#friend").hasClass("unfriend")) { ....}
```

To change the class the also use Jquery to

```
$("#friend").on ('click', function () {
    $("#friend").removeClass("unfriend").addClass("friend");
});
```

or

```
$("#friend").attr( "class", "friend" );   // replace only
```

To set the text simply

```
$("#friend").text ("Hi");
```

So the simply solution is to use Jquery and to do

```
$("#friend").on ('click', function () {
    $("#friend").attr( "class", "friend" );
    $("#friend").text ("Hi");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering your  question , you can simply do this :

**HTML :**

```
<a href="#" id="friend" class="unfriend" onclick="callAjax();">Unfriend</a>
```

**JS:**

```
$("#friend").click(function () {
    document.getElementById('friend').innerHTML = 'hi';
    $("#friend").removeClass("unfriend").addClass("friend");
});

function callAjax() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/your_URL",
        context: document.body
    }).done(function () {
        $(this).addClass("done");
    });
}
```

Fiddle for reference : http://jsfiddle.net/bm7Er/2/